# Can I open the contact card from Lync for Business?

Tags: html, skype, lync, skype-for-business

I have an application running on an internal server that can open Skype chats in Lync for Business using the following:

```
<a href="sip:martin@corporation.com">Chat with Martin</a>
```

Is it possible to open the contact card with a URL? The contact card is found by right clicking a user in the chat pane and then clicking `See Contact Card`.